# How to load spring application.yml from S3

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-boot-test

I have a bunch of spring application.yml properties file in S3 bucket for a different environment. I want to load the property files from the S3 bucket in order to guarantee a stateless configuration.

```
// Config Object
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "yaml")
public class YamlFooProperties {
    private String name;
    private List<String> aliases;
    // standard getter and setters
}

// foo.yml file located in S3 bucket
yaml:
  name: foo
  aliases:
    - abc
    - xyz
```

How can get my spring-boot application to load those properties and make then available when the application starts?

I'm using spring-boot version 2.2.6.RELEASE and Java 11.

Comment: According to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties#reloading-from-file it is possible to inject properties from a file using the `–spring.config.location=file://{path to file}.` Can it assist?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Write some very simple startup scripts, which first fetch (say `curl`) from S3 to local file (say `s3-config.yaml`) and then start your app normally.

Method 2: If you are using Kubernetes (which is a good idea to deploy systems), you can use other ways such as `ConfigMap` or `Helm` to deploy your app to satisfy your need of "guarantee a stateless configuration".

Method 3: If you only want Java (no script, no k8s, etc), then you may write down some simple Java code which fetches file from S3, and then call your SpringBootApplication's start with these data.

Comment: We need a solution in java where the app does this i.e. loads the properties file

Comment: Step 3 would be the way, However I'm not sure how to go about it. The must be a simple way to load external resource from s3 and the populate the config object on startup

Comment: @breaktop S3 should provide you a Java API (e.g. maven package). Then inside that API there should be one method, say, `S3.downloadFile("my_url")` which will load your s3 data into memory or local file. Thus you will only need to write several lines of code to fetch that yaml file.

Comment: After downloading the file, how would you go about setting up the config object. I mean how would you wire together the object values from the yml file. I've googled but couldn't way to do this

Comment: @breaktop You can put it in local disk, say `my-downloaded-file.yaml` and then pass it to Spring. About how to pass it, the most naive way (may exist better ways) is to set the environment variables.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to store the configs in s3. The default option Spring Cloud offers is a git-backed storage, which seems more favourable to me. However, there is S3 support as well.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_aws_s3_backend

This way your configuration server has a `EnvironmentRepository` configured to use an S3 bucket as an underlaying storage.

Comment: Is the a working example I can have a look at using this approach

Comment: Is it correct that you need a Spring Cloud Config server instance for this?